# chrome CORB issue for 3rd party api's request from angular 7 application

Tags: angular, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools, angular7

I wrote a code to fetch the data from the 3rd party API. It has worked in both postman collection and firefox browser. but in google chrome, it shows CORB error even though I enabled a CORS extension.

**ts file called popup.component.ts**

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PopupService } from './popup.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-popup',
  templateUrl: './popup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./popup.component.scss']
})
export class PopupComponent implements OnInit {

rowData: any = [];

constructor(
private popupService: PopupService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.GpGetAllValues();
  }

  GpGetAllValues() {
 this.popupService.GpGetAllValues()
  .subscribe(
    data => {
       console.log('successfully get all data --- ', data);
       this.rowData = data.categories;
       console.log('after set the categories are -----   ', this.rowData);
    },
    error => {
       console.log('cannot able to get all data --- ', error);
    }
    );
}

}
```

**service file called popup.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PopupService {

  constructor(
private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

GpGetAllValues(): Observable<any> {
 return this.http.get(`https://api.stlouisfed.org/fred/category?category_id=125&api_key=1d6109900692021b3c0e18d9a1c9591f&file_type=json`);
}

}
```

[image]

In the above screenshot. I enabled a CORS extension but I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try Closing the browser and killing all the chrome instances and restart the browser from cmd prompt [chrome.exe" --disable-web-security]